How to convert Xarray Dataset to a Darts Time Series

I have an Xarray dataset object with lat/lon/time coordinates This is a map of climate data. I want to convert this to an Darts TimeSeries object in order to train models on it. There is a function to convert a Xarray object to a TimeSeries but it requires three fields of "time", "components" and "samples". How do I convert my xarray dataset to this format?
I tried this, but got KeyError: 'component'
vi_time_series = TimeSeries.from_xarray(ds.vegetation_index)

